# Python3 - Have a list with elements inside with `b` and `\n` characters, such as "b"5.1. Please try\n5.1.1". Is there an easy way to decode/fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python3, I currently have a list with elements of the list being like:

```
'b"5.1. Please try\n5.1.1 the recipient's email address or\n5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at\n5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser 1-v6si3763255qtb.106 - gsmtp"'
```

There appears to be a byte element in the front and sproadically I see `\n`'s everywhere.

Is there a way to make this clean text? Would it require a function that goes into each element like this of my list or is there a function that can be applied to a list without looping? Thanks!

Comment: So you don't want a byte string or any \n's?

Comment: You appear to have called `str` on a bytestring at some point. You should figure out where that happened and fix it instead of trying to post-process the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your list:

```
[e[2:-2].replace("\n",' ') for e in yourlist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you somehow got the `repr` of a bytestring inside a string. It would be best to figure out the root cause of where that happened, otherwise you can clean it up with regex.

```
import re
re.sub(r'\n', ' ', re.sub(r'^b"(.*)"$', r'\1', dirty_string))
```